# Using an int variable in system() function c++

Tags: c++

I need using an int veriable in system() function for my c++ program.
for example:

- int a = 0;
- system("echo "a" ");

but i get an error and i need help about how i use this like that
Error:
C++ user-defined literal operator not found

Comment: Is the actual question: "How to convert an integer to string? And how to concatenate strings?" In that case the answer is `std::to_string` and `+`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's never going to work.  C++ doesn't plug integers into strings that way.  Instead, you can do:

```
int a = 42;
std::string s = "echo " + std::to_string (a);
system (s.c_str ());
```

Also, you might consult [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), in order to learn the language properly.